# Is it possible to use a variable that is a dependent variable in one model as an independent variable in another model at the same time?

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, variable

Let's say you have a dataset with variables A,B,C,D,E, and you want to build two model to predict D,E.
In this case, can we use A,B,C in one model to predict D and A,B,D as dependent variables in another model to predict E?

Comment: it's possible to do stuff kinda like this, yes. Can you tell us a little more about why you would be interested in such a thing, i.e. what kind of application you have in mind? Potentially, you might be interested in the idea of "Structural Equation Models" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_equation_modeling)

Comment: It is called structural equation model.

Comment: This happened in an agricultural AI competition in Korea, and the evaluators said that the model structure and approach were good, but the problem was that they didn't use domain knowledge or common sense (tomato production is affected by temperature and humidity). This approach was designed because there were too many missing values, and I don't understand why the data analysis process and model techniques are advancing if we can solve the problem based on common sense.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.  This type of model is usually referred to as a **hierarchical model**.  In this particular case, you would have a two-step hierarchical model with A, B, C at the base, then D at the first step of the hierarchy, then E at the second step of the hierarchy.

Your model would consist of a set of stipulated conditional distributions for each step of the hierarchy and your inference and prediction would occur by using your data to estimate the relevant conditional distributions at each step.  (You particular hierarchical model assumes that E is independent of C once you condition on A, B, D, so that assumption would be included in your stipulated conditional distributions in your model.)